# sustituir valores por índice de un Dataframe de pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

Estoy realizando un tratamiento de datos sobre un Dataframe. El caso es que tengo 3 columnas de tiempos en dicho Dataframe. Digamos columna A, B y C.
Para rellenar los valores NaN de la columna C cuando A y B no son valores NaN, he optado por el siguiente procedimiento:

1º Calculo los tiempos medios que van a ser los que sustituiran los valores NaN.
( como objetos "pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta")

2º Busco las lineas que cumplen dicha condicion con este código:

```
A_B_no_vacio = df_general['C'].isnull() & np.invert(df_general['A'].isnull()) & np.invert(df_general['B'].isnull())

indice = df_general[A_B_no_vacio].index
```

Hasta aquí, todo parece marchar bien. Pero el problema es cuando trato de asignar la columna B mas la suma de tiempo medio para los valores de la columna C según índices.

(sumando objetos Timestamp con objetos Timedelta)

Lo curioso es que si los sumo sin asignarlo a ninguna variable, no me da error, si no que lo suma perfectamente.

He probado varias maneras, pero todos me dan como resultado valores NaT para dichos elementos.

Aquí pongo un par de ejemplos de los intentos:

```
df_general.loc[indice, ["C"]] = df_general.loc[indice, ['B']] + tiempo_medio_salida

df_general.loc[indice, ["C"]].fillna(df_general.loc[indice, ['B']] + tiempo_medio_salida)
```

Agradecería muchísimo un método para sustituir los valores Nan pero solo bajo la condición que he definido en los índices.

Aquí pongo un ejemplo del Dataset:

[image: index A; B; C; 1 NaT 2019-01-02 07:27:40 2019-01-02 07:39:10 2 2019-01-02 07:39:10 2019-01-02 16:00:59 2019-01-02 16:07:25 3 2019-01-02 07:54:27 2019-01-02 08:07:28 2019-01-02 08:35:14 4 2019-01-02 07:54:27 2019-01-02 08:07:28 2019-01-02 08:35:14 5 2019-01-02 10:58:11 2019-01-02 11:11:32 2019-01-02 11:24:53]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar algunas líneas de tu `dataframe`? Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que al intentar asignar el valor estás intentando filtrar la columna "B" también, por eso te devuelve errores

Cree un `dataframe` como ejemplo para mostrar la solución

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

dateparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', parse_dates=['A', 'B', 'C'], date_parser=dateparse)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve

```
    A                   B                   C
0   2019-01-02 07:39:10 2019-01-02 16:00:59 2019-01-02 16:07:25
1   2019-01-02 07:40:11 2019-01-02 16:10:59 2019-01-02 16:17:25
2   2019-01-02 07:45:24 2019-01-02 16:20:59 NaT
3   2019-01-02 07:54:27 2019-01-02 16:30:59 2019-01-02 16:27:25
4   NaT                 2019-01-02 16:40:59 NaT
5   2019-01-02 07:13:30 2019-01-02 16:50:59 NaT
6   2019-01-02 07:22:07 2019-01-02 16:15:59 2019-01-02 16:37:25
7   2019-01-02 07:09:09 2019-01-02 16:25:59 NaT
```

Para obtener las filas donde "A" y "B" tienen valores pero "C" no, creamos el siguiente filtro

```
filtro = df['C'].isna() & df['A'].notna() & df['B'].notna()
```

Luego obtenemos los índices

```
indices = df[filtro].index
```

En tu pregunta no especificas como estas creando el `timedelta` así que a modo de ejemplo yo lo calculé así (Esto devuelve el promedio entre la diferencia de tiempos de "A" y "B")

```
delta = (df['B']-df['A']).mean()
```

Por último asignamos los nuevos valores a la columna "C" pero únicamente en las filas que cumplan con el filtro

```
df.loc[indices, 'C'] = df['B'] + delta
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    A                   B                   C
0   2019-01-02 07:39:10 2019-01-02 16:00:59 2019-01-02 16:07:25
1   2019-01-02 07:40:11 2019-01-02 16:10:59 2019-01-02 16:17:25
2   2019-01-02 07:45:24 2019-01-02 16:20:59 2019-01-03 01:11:24
3   2019-01-02 07:54:27 2019-01-02 16:30:59 2019-01-02 16:27:25
4   NaT                 2019-01-02 16:40:59 NaT
5   2019-01-02 07:13:30 2019-01-02 16:50:59 2019-01-03 01:41:24
6   2019-01-02 07:22:07 2019-01-02 16:15:59 2019-01-02 16:37:25
7   2019-01-02 07:09:09 2019-01-02 16:25:59 2019-01-03 01:16:24
```